# Regarding post requests

Tags: javascript, php, callback

Say I have the code:

```
var testVar = 0;
var newVar = "";

function(){
    var info = "hello";
    $.post("test.php", {"info":info}, function(data){
        if(data == "success"){
             testVar = 1;
        }
        else{
             testVar = 0;
        }
    });
    $.post("new.php", {"testVar":testVar}, function(data2){
        if(data2 == "success"){
            newVar = "Complete";
        }
        else{
            newVar = "Failed";
        }
    });
}
```

Assumning test.php returns "success" and new.php needs a a 1 for testVar to return success, how do I get a "Complete" for newVar? I'm guessing that the second post request would happen before the first returns the data.

Comment: put the second post INSIDE the callback of the first post request (so next to testVar=1)

Comment: I know I can do that, but am wondering what if the function had to be like this for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var testVar = 0;
var newVar = "";

var secondFunction = function(){
     $.post("new.php", {"testVar":testVar}, function(data2){
        if(data2 == "success"){
            newVar = "Complete";
        }
        else{
            newVar = "Failed";
        }
    });
};
function(){
    var info = "hello";
    $.post("test.php", {"info":info}, function(data){
        if(data == "success"){
             testVar = 1;
        }
        else{
             testVar = 0;
        }
        secondFunction();
    });

}
```

Comment: Yeah I know that, that's how I solved it. But does the second post request get fired before the callback. How does that work in a browser. Does it suspend that part of the function and continue.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters for the second request depend on the results coming from the first,
then make sure you send the requests in sequence,
meaning send the second `post` only after you have the response from the first.

Also you should prepare your responses to include a flag for success and another for the payload.

Successful operation

```
{success : "true", message : "operation successful", value : "1"}
```

Operation failed

```
{success : "false", message : "operation failed", value : "0"}
```

Consider the following example

```
function(){

    var info = "hello";

    $.post("test.php", {"info":info}, function(data){

        if (data.success != false){

            $.post("new.php", {"testVar":data.value}, function(data){
                if (data.success != false){
                    console.log(data.message) // this is the success message from the second request
                    // process the data from the second response,
                    // var = data.value ...
                }
                else{
                    console.log(data.message) // handle the failed state for the second request
                }
            },"json");

        }
        else{
            console.log(data.message)
        }

    },"json");

}
```

The second request will be fired only if the first one has been successful.
You have some consistency in your responses, the contents of `value` can be a single value, an array or an object.
Having values for success and a message, you can easily track what happened and if needed bring up notifications.